# What is Gudetama's catch phrase? Is it だりー or だるい?

Tags: words, slang, listening

On [Netflix, in the first episode](https://www.netflix.com/watch/81287073?trackId=14277283), at 00:43 he says it. Netflix translates it as "what a drag". It sounds to me like 「だりー」 not 「だるい」. But maybe I'm mishearing?

The dictionary says だるい means sluggish; languid; listless; heavy. Google translates it as "tired". Which seems like a good fit.

I did find this image of だるい but I'm not sure if it's the catch phrase or just another related phrase.

What is Gudetama saying? What's his catch phrase?

[image: gudetama egg saying だるい]

Comment: It's the same word as だるい but pronounced with a slangy accent.